# iOS - notification center features without enabling push notifications?

Tags: ios, push-notification, application-settings

My app is handling messages among users in active and background modes using a separate queuing and delivery system.

Is there a way I can tie my app into the Settings | Notification Center so that users can pick the alert style, enable or disable the badge app icon, and all those other features, without setting up push notifications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not. See [``Can I have my app in notification centre by default?´´](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7748100/ios-5-can-i-have-my-app-in-notification-center-by-default) for a similar issue.